# Excel VBA to: APPEND only modified records from Excel to Access

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, adodb

I have an excel spreadsheet which downloads the most up-to-date record set from a database via ADODB connection. Most up-to-date records are base on the import date/time. Once the information has been loaded onto the Excel Spreadsheet, I want the analyst/end-user to update any record as they see fit. When the analyst click the submit button, I only want the modified record(s) to be APPEND into the same table in MS Access 2007 database, which sits on a share drive. The database will automatically add an import date/time for each record.

**My problem:** I want to **only APPEND the newly modified records**. Thus I will have a historical log of what was updated and when. Currently I am appending the entire record set to MS Access 2007 while including today’s date/time stamp, this is causing redundant records with different timestamps.

The code below represents my current process. Please note I have public variables.

```
Private Sub db_CodeAmendment_Upload

    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim i, j, rw, co As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

    Sheets("sCodeMatrix").Visible = True

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sCodeMatrix").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear

        For Each sh In Worksheets
            If sh.Name <> "sCodeMatrix" Then sh.Visible = xlSheetHidden
        Next

    Sheets("sCodeMatrix").Select
    Sheets("sCodeMatrix").Activate

    rw = Range("A500").End(xlUp).Row
    co = Range("CZ1").End(xlToLeft).Column


    With cnn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .Open TARGET_DB
    End With

    rst.CursorLocation = adUseServer
    rst.Open Source:="tblCodeMatrix", ActiveConnection:=cnn, CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, LockType:=adLockOptimistic, Options:=adCmdTable

    'Load all records from Excel to Access.'
    For i = 2 To rw
        rst.AddNew
        For j = 1 To co
            rst(Cells(1, j).Value) = Cells(i, j).Value
        Next j
        rst.Update
    Next i

    ' Close the connection '
    On Error Resume Next
    rst.Close
    cnn.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cnn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a specific *question* in your question, so I assume that you are asking for general guidance on how to do this. I would suggest the following algorithm:

- Loop through your spreadsheet rows

  - Detect if the the record has been changed.
  - If it has been changed:

    - Add it as a new record to Access.

---

A few options come to mind for determining whether a record has changed:

- Query the record from the Access database and compare it field by field, or
- when inserting the data to the Excel sheet, import it *twice* (once into the visible area and once into some hidden columns further out to the right). This allows you to compare Excel cell to determine whether something was changed.

Comment: It is easy enough to link an Excel spreadsheet to Access, as long as the data is organized. Comparing fields / columns then becomes a matter of simple queries.

Comment: @Heinzi , thanks for the insight… can you provide a generic code how to do the loop and detect the changes? Something high-level so I can work off of. I was thinking concatenating all the columns on both end and do a dcount; when the count is zero, I would append that record. But I don’t know how to even start coding that.

Comment: @Remou, you bring a valid point… but this spreadsheet is distributed to multiple users. When a spreadsheet is open with a link, it will lock database. Therefore the other users are unable to push updates.